# Weight spaces of irreducible highest weight module with respect to a maximal root

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ is a simple Lie algeba. Then we can prove that it has a unique maximal root, denoted by $\lambda$. Now consider the unique (up to isomorphism) irreducible highest weight space $L(\lambda)$. Then I know that each weight $\mu$ of $L(\lambda)$ is of the form $\lambda-k_1\alpha_1-\cdots-k_m\alpha_m$, where $k_i\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}$ and $\alpha_i$ are positive roots. And the corresponding highest weight vectors are $x_{-\alpha_1}^{k_1}\cdots x_{-\alpha_m}^{k_m}v$, where $v$ is the highest weight vector with respect to $\lambda$ and $x_{-\alpha_i}$ is in the root space $\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha_i}$. Now I want to show that the vector $x_{-\alpha_1}^{k_1}\cdots x_{-\alpha_m}^{k_m}v$ is non-zero if and only if its weight is a root of $\mathfrak{g}$ i.e. $\lambda-k_1\alpha_1-\cdots-k_m\alpha_m$ is a root. I could not find any clues in the textbook. Could anyone provide some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question. The representation $L(\lambda)$ is isomorphic to the adjoint representation (more or less by construction), so the statement more or less holds be definition.

Comment: I mean that the weights of $L(\lambda)$ are exactly all the roots of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: The roots by definition are the non-zero weights of the adjoint representation, which is isomorphic to $L(\lambda)$ by the theorem of the hightest weight. So the original statement is not entirely correct, you have to deal with the zero-weight space separately.

Comment: Yes, it is. It should be $\sum\limits_{\beta\in R}e^\beta+1$.

Comment: Not quite, the zero weight space is the Cartan subalgebra, so its dimension is the tank of $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: But as a quotient module of the Verma's module, the dimension of each weight space should be $1$. Am I right? The Lie algebra here is simple.

Comment: This is the adjoint representation, so weight spaces are one-dimensional, except for the weight zero, for which the weight space is the Cartan subalgebra. And for quotients of Verma modules, weihgt spaces can be higher dimensional (this happens very often).